# How to create tabs in markdown?

Tags: reactjs, markdown, render, next.js13

I am creating a blog using Next.js and Markdown and want to render tabs to show data.
Please suggest how I can achieve the following.

[image]

[image]

This example is from leetcode. I want the same kind of functionality.

Comment: This isn't functionality available in markdown, you probably need some kind of plugin

Comment: What's your markdown interpreter?

Comment: @Antax I can use any interpreter
Please suggest with such functionality